# Voltage fault injection possible on switch output?

Tags: voltage, switches, fault

I am required to check that the software in a system correctly handles a fault condition from a high side power switch.  The switch has a current sense pin which sends a voltage back to a microcontroller to let the microcontroller know all is well or not.

I could destructively cut the track and simply add the voltage signal but the same track is required later in the test process, (plus everytime I do that I destroy an expensive PCB).

If I inject the voltage directly to the output of the switch using a PSU, what would happen?

Comment: depends on the supply... perhaps bad things, better to inject transient faults with a large suitable cap or follow IEC Stds for fault injection tests for ESD and other events.  or inject the fault internally to disable the driver, there are thousands of fault types not just this one.e.g. add an internal load to inject a simulation to test OCP and UVP. It takes a good Test Engineer to understand the design to test for fault conditions with non-destructive tests NDT

Comment: As you are (presumably repeatedly) testing the software, you "destroy" precisely ONE expensive PCB, by cutting the track and adding a (software controlled relay) switch across it for the later tests, and any other adaptations necessary (debug interface, etc) That PCB then becomes the software test harness.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a [Logic Pulser](https://www.google.com/search?q=logic%20pulser).  It is designed to override the logic state at the probed point with a brief pulse of the opposite polarity of the sensed voltage.  The pulse is so short that it does not damage the device that is driving the signal.  You connect the pulser to the same power supply as the chip that is driving the signal and then put the metal point on the signal that you want to toggle.

Logic pulsers are kind of old school, so many require a minumum of 5V (from TTL days) to run.  The [specifications for the one pictured below](http://www.spiratronics.com/data/1880.pdf) say that it runs from 3V-15V.  Assuming you are not trying to pulse something with lower impedance than the probe, it should be able to toggle your signal for testing.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  I'm meant to inject a voltage profile over 8 minutes, so guessing this is not the ideal method for my implementation.

Comment: You are right.  It is only good for short changes.  Assuming that the MCU is reading the current sensor with a high impedance input, you could patch the board to put a resistor in series with the sensor signal.  Then put in a test point on the MCU side of the resistor to override the sensor output for testing without affecting the sensor.